# Слово "прибамбас"

Tags: этимология

Кто-нибудь знает происхождение слова "прибамбас"? Слово широко ходит в народе, значение довольно понятное.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Слово это родственно "прибаутке" и изначально обозрачало шутку, розыгрыш (от "баска" — игрушка).
Потом стало употрябляться с более сленговым оттенком в значение "излишество", "излишнее дополнение к чему-то" или, позже, "детали, дополнительные функции некоего устройства".

Comment: Классный ответ! От себя хочу добавить, что баска - от  **баса** (краса). Баской - красивый. Из Даля :

"" Баса
ж. сев. бас ? м. яросл. краса, красота,
хорошество, пригожество, нарядность,
изящество; украшение, наряд, украса,
прикраса. То и баса, что руса коса.
Сколько **прибасов** ни надевай, а басы  не прибудет.""

Comment: О "баске" сразу две версии. А "бам" откуда? Для аллитерации?

Comment: Скорее всего так! Ведь сначала были прибабасы, без 'м'. Ср. : забабахать.

Answer (score 1):

А забавное слово. Версии из Вики мне не слишком нравятся, малодоказательно как-то все, но других привести не могу. Тем не менее некоторая полезная информация.

О "прибабасах без М" никогда не слышал.

gramma полагает "прибамбас" искуственным словом, созданным по имеющейся словообразовательной модели. 
Вопрос 1069:    Откуда произошли жаргонные слова: офигеть, прикол, прибамбасы?
Ответ:   Ни один из словарей, описывающих значения и оттенки значений жаргонных слов, не может "вычислить" их этимологию, ибо жаргонизмы, как правило, возникают либо на основе переосмысления значений слов литературного языка (прикалывать - прикол), либо путем создания искусственных слов по существующей словобразовательной модели (прибамбасы). Можно только гадать, каким образом возникло слово "фига", от которого образован глагол "офигеть", и имеет ли оно какую-либо связь с экзотическим плодом.
http://www.gramma.ru/ARRM/?RG1=11&flag=1&RG2=all&page=9&PHPSESSID=4172b9e6bee814ce8ee0a224b195cfd3

Могу точно сказать, что впервые это слово я услышал еще дошкольником в начале шестидесятых - и именно во множественном числе - прибамбасы. Значение, кстати, было несколько другое, говоря современным языком слово означало неадекватности в поведении. "Она с прибамбасами" однозначно означало "она с отклонениями". Еще в семидесятых годах в "Юности" (?) была некая "Леночка Прибамбасова", что тоже можно считать неким свидетельством в пользу указанного значения...

Еще стоит заметить, что "бамбас" по некоторым данным - "Аппарат для курения анаши". Это вполне согласуется с исходным. Правда непонятно, что тут первично.